# how to create a radio button in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

this is jqgrid cheack box but i will not take the value at the time of  click the submit button please any one help me..

```
edittype:'custom',
    editoptions: {
              custom_element: function() {
                  var elemStr = '<div class="col-xs-3">'+
                    '<label>'+
                    '   <input type="checkbox" class="ace ace-switch ace-switch-4" name="alternateMobileNumber">'+
                    '   <span class="lbl"></span>'+
                    '</label>';
                  return $(elemStr)[0];
              },
              custom_value: function(elem) {
                 var op = ($('input[name="alternateMobileNumber.value()"]').attr('checked'))? "1":"0";
                return op;
              }
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `custom value function` like,

```
custom_value: function(elem) {
   var op = $('input[name="alternateMobileNumber"]').prop('checked') ? "1" : "0";
   return op;
}
```